# How to continue running pytest when python crashes?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm running `GTK GUI` tests with `pytest-xdist` `pytest`plugin via following command

```
C:\python.exe -m pytest --showlocals --durations=10 -n1 C:\code\tests\gui
```

on `Windows 7`.

Python process tends to have `INTERNALERROR` for unknown reasons to me so I use `-n1` to restart the process again with remaining tests.
But there is a problem, dialog bellow pauses creation of a new process and I don't know how to close it automatically.
[image]

Is there a way to avoid creation of new dialogs or any other way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

So the dialog is generated by windows, so to disable it follow these steps:

1. Start *gpedit.msc*
2. Navigate to *Computer Configuration*->*Administrative Templates*->*Windows Components*->*Windows Error Reporting*
3. On right pane select *Prevent display of the user interface for critical errors* and set *Enabled*